How to provide Facebook login app verification details when app is still in progress
I've created a facebook login app and Im trying to get it reviewed.
Before I can go further I need to complete the App verification details
It states to Provide all the necessary details for how a Facebook reviewer can log in to your app
Im confused because if I try to use the supplied app id and secret it states that the app is still in progress.
How can I allow access for a FB tester if the app is still in review?

I have the same problem. It's circular logic, isn't it ?

did you resolve your situation ?

Yes, very weird, turns out I dont think FB even logged into the account I set up for them. I just went ahead and its been working since day 1.
